# HiveServer2 not picking up the right Kerberos Principal while starting up

Tags: hive, kerberos

We have put these entries in hive-site.xml:

- hive.server2.authentication : KERBEROS
- hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.keytab : /tmp/hive.keytab
- hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal : hive/FQDN of the hive VM@xxxxxxxx.COM

Using kinit command on the hive VM, we have verified that Kerberos principal and the keytab file are valid:

> kinit -t FILE:/tmp/hive.keytab -k hive/FQDN of the hive VM@xxxxxxxx.COM

Then if we do,

> klist

it shows the same in Ticket Cache as the default Principal.

But, when we try to start the HiveServer2 using :

> sudo service hive-server2 start

it throws the exception :
Starting HiveServer2
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Kerberos principal should have 3 parts: **hive**
at org.apache.hive.service.auth.HiveAuthFactory.getAuthTransFactory(HiveAuthFactory.java:127)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.run(ThriftCLIService.java:505)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

When we try to start the service (using ./hiveserver2) with any other logged in user, say User123, it throws the same exception with :
Starting HiveServer2
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Kerberos principal should have 3 parts: **User123**
at org.apache.hive.service.auth.HiveAuthFactory.getAuthTransFactory(HiveAuthFactory.java:127)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.run(ThriftCLIService.java:505)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

**Shouldn’t Kerberos Principal be picked up from the hive-site.xml and not the login user?** Are we missing out something.

--
I have created a principal hive/FQDN of the hive VM@xxxxxxxx.COM  in advance and created a keytab file for it.
We are on CDH 4.7 (not installed using CM), OEL6 and Kerberos5

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos secuirty should be configured for HDFS and MR too, and not just HIVE.